# printing in pdf in java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

i am using spring MVC and angularJS and RestfulApi and MongoDB for database

what i need is to print whole data of a list in a pdf version.

Suppose i have a single page with two components userlist and employeelist
the

i am fetching 10 rows - 10 rows in userlist and employee_list but when i click on print button of a specific component then his whole data should fetch and represent automatically in tabular form and print in a pdf how can i do it in java? or i need angular for this? please enlight me

how can i intialte a print command and show the whole data in that pdf?

Comment: Can you use PDFbox instead ??(https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis can it generate table dynamically?

Comment: Yes.Also Its very good and popular too.Si you will find plenty of doc and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use below **java code** for printing pdf which is located in pdfpath(server path)

Note : Before using below code import `java.awt.Desktop` class.

```
Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}
desktop.print(new File(pdfpath));
```